# Testing letsrate controller. RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to test letsrate generated controller.
But I don;t know how do this, because I can not understand how it works.
**rater_controller.rb**

```
class RaterController < ApplicationController

  def create
    if user_signed_in?
      obj = params[:klass].classify.constantize.find(params[:id])
      obj.rate params[:score].to_i, current_user, params[:dimension]

      render :json => true
    else
      render :json => false
    end
  end

end
```

**UPDATE**

[Letsrate](https://github.com/muratguzel/letsrate) is a gem for rails

**rater_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe RaterController do

  describe 'POST create' do
    let(:valid_attributes)do {
    klass: 'Hotel',
    dimension: 'rating',
    score: '5'
    }
    end

    it 'user signed in' do
      user = create(:user)
      hotel = create(:hotel)
      post :create, { rate: valid_attributes, rater_id: user.id, rateble_id: hotel.id }
      sign_in user


    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How the controller works? I mean, it only renders true/false. Apparently there's a side effect contained in obj.rate as well, so you'll want to check that it's properly updated based on the params.

Comment: I don't know how controller works, I do not really need to describe the action creatу in order to after-check this render?

Answer (score 1):

The source code you posted makes it pretty obvious how it works.  You need to call the create action in RaterController with these params: klass, id, score, dimension.  Let's say the klass param is "Restaurant", which is also the name of an ActiveRecord model class.  The controller will query the database for a restaurant with the specified ID.  Then it will call the `rate` method on that object with the specified parameters, which presumably inserts a row into the database representing the user's new rating.  To test it, you could simply call the controller action and then check to make sure the row got added to the database.

Comment: I created a new object and then evaluate it and in the logs here poluchli this answer. see update

Comment: Now I can write the incoming arguments to rate, because I know them and check render:)I am very grateful to you, now I'll know that the easiest way to see what's happening in the logs, I used to not think out

Comment: I'm sorry, tell me plz, how testing this  `render :json => true` when user signed in ? see update

Comment: I don't know exactly what you should write but try looking at `response` and `response.body` to see if one of those has the JSON string returned by the controller.